# setTimeout placed in header , how can i restrict to run 1 time

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i make sure this doesn't execute again. I am redirecting all my pages to a single page on my site. It keeps refreshing/reloading that page because the script is placed in the header and must be.

```
   setTimeout(function(){
     window.location="mysite/page";
   },1000);
```

Comment: It only runs one time, if you don't want it to run on `mysite/page`, remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an hash to your url when you refresh the page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var loc = window.location.href;
    if (loc.indexOf ("#DoNotRefresh") < 0) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location="#DoNotRefresh";
        },1000);
    }
    console.log(new Date());
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just check to see if the location is already set?

```
  if(window.location !== 'mysite/page')
     {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
         window.location = 'mysite/page';
        }, 1000); 
     }
```